# unable to post using curl in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am leaning laravel. I am working on `Rest API`. I have made the `controller` to post using curl as follow

```
public function post_index()
{

        $cat = Input::json();
        $dbCat = new Category();
        $dbCat->code = $cat->code;
        $dbCat->name = $cat->name;
        $dbCat->save();
        return $dbCat->toJson();


}
```

when I am trying to post using curl then i am getting following error

```
Message:

Trying to get property of non-object
Location:

C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\application\controllers\api\category.php on line 22
```

and the stack trace is

```
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 22)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\application\controllers\api\category.php(22): Laravel\{closure}(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 22, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Api_Category_Controller->post_index()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\routing\controller.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\routing\controller.php(285): Laravel\Routing\Controller->response('index', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\routing\controller.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Controller->execute('index', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\routing\route.php(153): Laravel\Routing\Controller::call('api.category@in...', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\routing\route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\laravel\laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\public\index.php(34): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#10 {main}
```

how can I come out through this problem ?

Comment: where is line 22 in the code?

Comment: Im not sure how the request looks like but according to the documentation you should get the json as normal.

>Note: Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like normal.

Comment: Please post the contents of C:\xampp\htdocs\NewBlog\application\controllers\api\category.php and the exact curl command you're using, so we can help you! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are filling $cat with Input::json() you'll need to make sure that you are sending a curl request that has a header that is setting the content type to application/json

curl isn't really built for sending json, are you able to send normal post fields instead?

Really... we need more information on your situation, like the code you are using to send a curl request

Comment: thanx, i am sending simple data and getting it, now I am trying to convert it using json_encode() and json_decode(), I am able to save data into database, but now the problem is that the data is being saved for two times ....

Comment: probably worth posting your solution then, in the case that somebody comes to this page looking for an answer, and if you get stuck with what you're on now then open a new question since it's a new issue

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what line 22 is, my suggestion would be to check that `$cat` is actually an object. It's most likely throwing that error because it's `null` or, as the error says, a non-object.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working as indicated in the other answer, and you are now encountering a problem with a "doubling up" of the json wrapper then I would suggest using eloquent_to_json() instead of json_encode()
http://laravel.com/api/function-eloquent_to_json.html